# Jmeter - How to listen for an inbound (subsequent to response) reply

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to Jmeter, just done a basic course and now on my first test plan trying to test messaging with our application.

I have sent in a message (https) that receives an acknowledgement in response that I can see and all is well there. The problem I have is that the application then sends the actual reply as a new message (same converstaion ID) and the test has stopped running by then.

How do I tell jmeter to stay active and listen for a specific inbound message that is a reply to the message sent by jmeter but not the immediate response?

Comment: Are you testing web sockets application?